# What do "reduced antipredator defense" and "reduced antipredator vigilance" mean?

Tags: zoology, ecology, population-dynamics, population-biology

The book [BIOMAT 2010](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8mu1SZLN3DgC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%22reduced%20antipredator%20defense%22&source=bl&ots=xVc6UGxOVh&sig=BHr513stvBU0mH49fLM4LaHqbiM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIysLavLb9yAIVz1OOCh2Y9A4T#v=onepage&q=%22reduced%20antipredator%20defense%22&f=false) (International Symposium on Mathematical and Computational Biology, edited by Rubem P. Mondaini) mentions the terms *reduced antipredator defense* and *reduced antipredator vigilance*.
Can you help me to make sense of them?

Comment: Do you mean "What is the definition of RAD? and What is the definition of RAV?"?

Comment: @Remi.b Yes. Where they are seen and what are those effects.

Comment: Where did you first encounter these terms? In the book you're citing? Does the book attempt at defining these terms at all?

Comment: @Remi.b Yes, in the book. Not defined those terms.

Comment: I edited your question. Feel free to rollback (or to further edit) if you don't like my edits. I would suggest that you make an attempt of what you understand of these terms so far. I personally have never encountered them before but I am not an ecologist.

Comment: A quote placing terminology into context is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When groups of prey use certain mechanisms to defend against predators, those mechanisms are known as antipredator defenses. For example, groups of tuna and starlings flock together to confuse predators. A reduction in this defense would be 'reduced antipredator defense'.

Groups of prey also exhibit shared antipredator vigilance, as in certain members of a group will look out for predators to protect the group. This is seen most predominantly in meerkats. A reduction is said vigilance would be a 'reduced antipredator vigilance'.

With reference to the Allee effect, which is what you appear to be reading about, this reduced antipredator defense and vigilance can significantly effect the population and the population growth.

Some related links:

- On the [ecological mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allee_effect#Ecological_mechanism) of the Allee effect.
- [Vigilance, predation risk, and the Allee effect in desert Bighorn sheep](http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.2193/0022-541X%282004%29068%5B0519%3AVPRATA%5D2.0.CO%3B2), a recent research paper.

Comment: Please explain in more details the term reduced antipredator vigilance. I understand the term 'reduced antipredator defense'

Comment: I think it's a good answer, but basing questions entirely on Wikipedia is not preferred, given its dynamic contents. Your info used may be gone from your link tomorrow.

Comment: Alright, I will find different sites to validate this information. Thanks!

Comment: @user1942348 Reduced antipredator vigilance would mean that the group of prey would not be able to detect the predator as well as earlier. This can be due to increased ability of the predator to hide and camouflage or isolation of prey from the predator for some time 
Here is a link you might want to look at : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1559846/

Comment: @malharkhushu Thanks a lot. Would you please give some examples where it is seen?

Comment: If (hypothetically) meerkats are taken to islands without predators for many generations, they would eventually forget to be vigilant about predators. When put back into a normal condition, they would not be able to detect and avoid predators. This was also seen in dodos, who could not survive when external predators were brought onto their isolated islands. There are quite a few more examples, but I can't remember any off hand. If I remember more, I will be sure to tell you